# QueryDSL How to CROSS join Expression such as StringExpression or StringTemplate instead of EntityPath?

Tags: postgresql, persistence, querydsl

I need to implement the following query:

```
select 
      et.id, 
      obj ->> 'item' as item, 
from example_table et,
   json_array_elements(et.data::json -> 'rows') obj 
where obj -> 'item' ->> 'itemDetails' is not null )
```

How do I CROSS JOIN **json_array_elements(...)** in this case, using QueryDSL?
For standard joins I simply use **com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLQuery.from()**.